# SSIS: Creating a variable expression but it is throwing error "DT_WSTR" and "DT_DATE" are incompatible

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, date, ssis

I'm creating an incremental load which would be pulling data from **ORACLE** to **SQL** Server. The incremental load will be based off a **MODIFIED_DATE** column.

I have created a **result set variable** that stores the **MAX modified_date** from the destination table. So the engine will only check the rows of the **MODIFIED_DATES** that are **greater** than the variable and perform a lookup to see if the row needs to be added, updated or deleted.

So I have my **MAX MODIFIED DATE RESULT SET** and I also have created another variable that will house the **SOURCE QUERY** which will be have a **WHERE** clause that see if the **MODIFIED_DATE** column is greater than the **MAX MODIFIED_DATE variable**.

Example:

```
Select column_name,column_name
From table
Where modified_date > '"+   @[User::LastModifiedDate]+ "'"
```

It is throwing me an error off:

> The data types "DT_WSTR" and "DT_DATE" are incompatible for binary operator "+". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Now, I have done a ton of searching but I cant seem to find a way to do this. The only solution that I found online is to **ADD A (DT_WSTR, 25)** in front of the variable which causes the variable expression to evaluate and this is the only way I can get the variable expression to evaluate.

**Example:**

```
(DT_WSTR, 25)  @[User::LastModifiedDate]+ "'"
```

When I run it it is telling me it is **NOT A VALID MONTH**

The `MODIFIED_DATE` column in the **DESTINATION** table is in SQL Server and it has a DataTime as the date type which reads like this:

```
2008-06-10 22:22:25.000
YYYY-MM-DD
```

The `MODIFIED_DATE` column in the **SOURCE** table in oracle reads like:

```
6/10/2008 10:22:25 PM
MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS
```

How would I be able to resolve this? Also what do you think is the best way to perform an incremental load based the `MODIFIED_DATE` column? Is my way one of the more efficient ways or is there another route I can take?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your SSIS component call the following statement:

```
Select column_name,column_name
From table
Where modified_date > to_date('whateverformat','"+ (DT_WSTR,25)@[User::LastModifiedDate]+ "')"
```

The problem is you are tangling the strings versus dates.  Your lastmodifieddate must be a string for the expression builder to function, but i suspect Oracle is expecting modified_date to be a date, so just use the to_date function

Comment: Ahh is see, let me try this. Thank you so much !